# A method returns null object when called from onCreate but returns correct value in onClick method

Tags: android, onclick, nullreferenceexception, oncreate

I am using wuapnjie/StickerView [library](https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView) in my app and one of the function getCurrentSticker in [StickerView](https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView/blob/master/sticker/src/main/java/com/xiaopo/flying/sticker/StickerView.java) class is returning null object reference when I called the method in onCreate method, but working perfectly when called from any onClick method. Any of your expertise will be very helpful. Thanks.

When I try to run the code in separate thread within runOnUiThread sometimes it is working and sometimes not. How come some code would work sometime and not the other time. I am very confused. Below is the piece of code which works in onClick method and not in onCreate method.

When I call addStickerNow in below code from onCreate, it returns null value. In onClick method it is returning actual value.

```
public class MainActiviy extends AppCompatActivity
{
private StickerView stickerView;
private Button button;
LinearLayout layout;

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = findViewById(R.id.lnr_draw);
    stickerView = (StickerView) findViewById(R.id.sticker_view);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    addStickerNow(); //It's not working.
}

public void onButtonClicked(View view)
{
  addStickerNow(); //It's working.
}

public void addStickerNow()
{
stickerView.addSticker(
        new TextSticker(getApplicationContext())
                .setText("TEXT")
                .setMaxTextSize(70)
                .setTextAlign(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER)
                .setMinTextSize(100)
        , Sticker.Position.TOP);

 int test = 1;  //1st breakpoint
 Sticker sticker = stickerView.getCurrentSticker();  // 2nd breakpoint
 int test2 = 1; //3rd breakpoint
 }
}
```

I tried to debug the app as per Mr.Hyde's suggestion and found the below difference when the addStickerNow is called from onCreate and onClick.

```
*1st breakpoint, when called from onCreate
this = {MainActivity@4424} 
stickerView = {StickerView@4427} "com.xiaopo.flying.sticker.StickerView{7b55d6d V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f070071 app:id/sticker_view}"

1st breakpoint, when called from onClick
this = {MainActivity@4424} 
stickerView = {StickerView@4427} "com.xiaopo.flying.sticker.StickerView{7b55d6d V.E...... ......ID 0,160-720,760 #7f070071 app:id/sticker_view}"*
```

*The main difference here is RectF of StickerView is **0,0-0,0** when called from onCreate and **0,160-720,760** when called from onClick. So something it is related to layout creation.*

The layout file is below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    tools:context="e.venkihero.stickerviewtest.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnr_draw"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.xiaopo.flying.sticker.StickerView
            android:id="@+id/sticker_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            app:showIcons="true">



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_bg1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </com.xiaopo.flying.sticker.StickerView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
        android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If anyone could explain why the piece of code (which is at the top) working fine in onClick method but returning null object reference in onCreate method that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Please add some part of your `MainActivity` too. Especially `OnCreate`.

Comment: add code how you are calling it from MainActivity OnCreate method?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde   The first piece of code I added initially was from onCreate only. Now I edited it to look it is being called from onCreate. (Note: This is not my actual MainActivity, but this I am trying to do. When I call addStickerNow from onCreate, returns Null pointer, but when it calls from onClick method (onButtonClicked) it is returning actual value.

Comment: @MilanHirpara please see the updated code now please

Comment: this is very unlikely but would you please use `this`, instead of `getApplicationContext()` in `new TextSticker(HERE)`.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde no luck :(

Comment: @Venkatesh Would you please put `addStickerNow()` in `onStart`, and if it doesn't work either, put it in `onResume`?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde I already tried it in onResume, but doesn't work. I ll try it in onStart and ll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde I tried in onStart as well, but no luck again.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde I even tried to perform programatically click on button like button.performClick() but that doesn't work either. Only when I actually click, it works.

Comment: Now you would trace it in debug mode. Put a breakpoint on line 13 (`addStickerNow(); //It's not working.`), and use **F7** repeatedly and see what's happening!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde I tried to debug as per your suggestion and I updated my findings in the question itself. I couldn't able to come to any conclusion what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Nitinkumar's below answer worked. It all comes from your suggestion of debugging the app. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems StickerView is dependent upon your overall layout to draw itself. Since in onCreate your layout is not drawn on your Activity so your StickerView's Rect is all 0.

Add following code inside `onCreate` to wait for layout to be drawn and then call your addSticker Method.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = yourLayout.getViewTreeObserver();

vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {                
        vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        addStickerNow()
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I exactly needed. It worked. Thanks for your answer. I am very new to Android development and so am not aware of it. This is a good learning experience.

Comment: I would love to upvote your answer.. but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do so coz I don't have 15 reputation point. Why this kind of weird rule I don't know. Once I get 15 reputation point I ll do it. Thanks.